# DateTime defaulting to 1970-01-01

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, datetime

I am writing a PHP form for my website. The HTML side asks the user for a date which they enter in MM/DD/YYYY format. When that string is sent to PHP the following code changes it to the form that MySQL will recognize

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$sqldate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

However when that date is entered into my MySQL database it is entered as 1970-01-01 and I can't figure out why.

NOTE: If I echo $sqldate I get the error Use of undefined constant sqldate - assumed 'sqldate' in C:/MYDIRECTORY

Comment: what is the type of your mySQL field? timestamp?

Comment: If your $date variable is NULL, strtotime() will return 1979-01-01. Print your your $date variable to make sure it isn't null, then do what @Mostafa suggested.

Comment: What is a sample value of `$_POST['date']` that you are seeing this occur for?

Comment: If i echo $date it returns for example 08/18/1994. However if I echo $sqldate I get an error:  Use of undefined constant sqldate - assumed 'sqldate' in C:\MYDIRECTORY

Comment: change the name of the var to datetest instead of sqldate

Comment: [Works for me.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5H1lJB) Whatever your issue is, it is not i nthis code. Judging by the error message you are getting you almost certainly have another issue elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like your variable misses the dollar in your echo.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
//build a date
$date = date_parse_from_format("m/d/Y", $_POST["date"]);
//output the bits
$sqldate = "$date[year]-$date[month]-$date[day]";
```

A Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 so your call to `strtotime()` is returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

How is DateTime working for you?

```
<?php
$dateStr = '08/18/2014';//$_POST['date'];
$dateTime = new DateTime($dateStr);
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

You're writing that the date format of the form is MM/DD/YYYY. Do you validate the input values to be sure that the format is always given?

Answer (score 0):

THis worked for me

```
$input_date= trim($_POST["input_date"]);
$strtotime= strtotime($input_date);
$date_format= date('Y-m-d',$strtotime);
```